# Migrating Postgresql 9.1 to 9.2 from an old server to a new server

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2008

In my old server, Postgresql 9.1 is installed and it contains a large scale of data. Now, I have got a new server and installed the latest version of Postgresql which is 9.2. I want to migrate the whole data from the old server to the new server. I looked at Postgresql documentation and there is a command to upgrade but it seems to explain upgrading in the same server. How could I approach for this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be very careful about changing both hardware and major versions of PostgreSQL at the same time.  If something goes wrong, it will greatly complicate figuring out what the problem is.

I do this as a two step process, first restore the database to the new server as the same version, then run pg_upgrade.  That means you have to have both versions of the software installed on the new server simultaneously.

Comment: Two postgresql versions in the same server can be another big source of confusion for a non experienced admin.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the database with [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-pgdump.html) and load it at the new server with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/app-psql.html). I think [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/pgupgrade.html) is better as an in place procedure.

Comment: As pg_dump command extracts postgresql to a script file. I have done the same thing with pgAdmin3 interface and I have the script file in hand. When loading this script file to the new server database, do I need to create all the tables in Postgresql 9.2 in new server?

Comment: @nudastack The pg_dump default created script is supposed to do everything for you. What exactly did you do in pgAdmin3? Simply do it with pg_dump.

Comment: What I did in pgAdmin3 was simply took the backup of the database as a script file from the old server.

Comment: @nudastack If you have lots of data in your DB - it might be faster to create a binary DB dump with `pg_dump` and restore it with `pg_restore`.

Comment: I think "pg_dump myDB > myBackup.sql" command will extract the script file of the myDB. Where should I run this command? In my old server I tried to run this command but "pg_dump" command wasn't recognized. I really appreciate your considerations.

Comment: @nudastack In a DOS prompt navigate to the postgresql bin folder. I don't have Windows experience so not sure where it is.

Comment: I found it in your way. The command is working in the bin directory. The database has many tables and sequences and index variables. When running "pg_dump myDB > myBackup.sql" command, will it extract all of them?

Comment: However, after running the command the prompt needs a password. I am entering the root password that I always connecting to the database but it is not accepted. What sort password does it want?